# What datatype do I use with bitmask_attributes gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bit-manipulation

I'm using this gem: https://github.com/joelmoss/bitmask_attributes

To be honest, I don't know what datatype i'm supposed to use in my migration.

Ive read through the documentation and don't see any mention of it. It seems to work if a try a few different datatypes which kind of worries me, I feel like if I choose the wrong one I'm going to be screwed and think it's working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column should be an integer column

If your database offers many sizes of integers you need to pick one big enough given the number of values you plan on storing in the bit mask - if you have 5 flags, the maximum value would be 31 (2**5 - 1)

Comment: This is a stupid question but, why is it storing it as a number like "21" if its using binary? Shouldnt it be like 11001 or something? By the way I have 7 values (monday-sunday).

Comment: 10101 and 21 and 0x15 are the same number - it's just how whatever program you are using the inspect the contents is choosing to present it to you.

Comment: As a side question, why was the 'binary' rails datatype (blob is mysql?)  allowing me to save '21' in it? i tried that and it still worked. Just trying to fully understand